# prevent selection in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to prevent certain sections of a block of text from being selected, while other parts can be.

```css
.unsel {
  font-weight: bold;
  user-select:none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Blah ljaskldfjalskdfjalksdfja kjalskd jfalksdjf askdfaskdskflaskjdflkas jflaskjflaksjlaksjfalksfj ksj fskfjaskl jkj slaj sasjflkasjf ks jaks fjaslkf j <span class="unsel">But you can't select me.</span> kajsdflkajs dsaslkf jalsk fjalks fjsl kfjs <span class="unsel">Or me, so there.</span>
</p>
```

When you highlight the text, the parts that can't be selected are not highlighted, but if I copy the text, the non-highlighted parts will still be copied.

I saw [this CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/) that says that in Chrome, the text is not hightlighted but can still be selected. So how can I prevent the text from being copied?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css

Comment: @BarneyChambers, the answers there all focus on preventing all selecting, I want to have some bits unselectable and prevent copying in the unhighlighted parts.

Comment: If you are using IE 9 or under, then it may not work.

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or a feature... https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80159 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=147490. Looks like there isn't a spec for the property, so different browsers are handling it different.

Comment: I'm using chrome, that's the whole point of the question: it only doesn't work in chrome